# What are $\lim \inf{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ and $\lim \sup{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ if $A$ is finite?

Tags: calculus, limsup-and-liminf

**Definition.** Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is called an *almost upper bound* of $A$ if there are only finitely many $y \in A$ for which $y \geq x$. Similarly we define almost lower bounds. Define $\lim \sup{A}$ to be the infimum of all almost upper bounds of $A$ and $\lim \inf{A}$ to be the supremum of all almost lower bounds of $A$.

> What are $\lim \inf{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ and $\lim \sup{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ if $A$ is finite?

Since $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is of infinite size, I don't see how about the upper bound part since there will always be infinitely many greater than any $x$. Thus, how would we define it for the empty set?

Comment: The "if $A$ is finite" part doesn't seem to make sense.  The definition of $lim\ inf\ \mathbb{Z}^+ $ doesn't include $A$ in it - it's just $ sup \left\{ x\ \middle|\ x \text{ is an almost lower bound of } \mathbb{Z}^+ \right\} $.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is unbounded above, it has no almost upper bounds. So $\limsup\mathbb{Z}^+=\inf(\varnothing)$. This is either undefined, or equal to $\infty$ (depending on your convention).

Now note that *every positive number* is an almost lower bound of $\mathbb{Z}^+$, so $\liminf\mathbb{Z}^+=\sup[0,\infty)$, which is again either undefined or equal to $\infty$, depending on your convention.